# Sitecore Solr Search on data sourced sublayouts

Tags: search, solr, sitecore

I have a page item which has sublayout which is data sourced to data item, My question is If I used solr search to search for a term that is contained within the content of the data item; Should the page item be returned by solr search or should I apply custom code to do that?

I am using sitecore 7.2 and solr version is 4.10.2-0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLR will return whatever you index, in this instance since it is just an item then it will return the item itself and not the link to the page that this item is referenced on.

Instead what you need to do is index the datasourced items as part of the main content item on which they are referenced. You can either do this as a [post-processor/computed field](http://kamsar.net/index.php/2014/05/indexing-subcontent/) or use a module like [Sitecore Datasource Indexer](http://sitecorefun.baziret.com/2014/06/sitecore-datasource-indexer/).